# How to identify when entering a conference call?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to identify when a **call goes from 1-to-1 to multiparty/conference call**?

Is any kind of broadcast or event called?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, the phone is oblivious to this -- such calls are handled by the carrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not at the moment.  This is managed by the system and is inaccessible to developers.  The closest you have is [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html), but you are only really able to access basic information about the phone.  I believe this is mainly for security reasons (so people can't "bug" phones with a simple program), but also because telephony is managed on a lower level, within the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The information his phone has regarding calls is not shared with your phone at any point doing the call or otherwise, it's shared with the towers.  there will be no app or software or hardware for that matter that can do what you need unless it's police sting ray