# How to detect conference call in Android?

Tags: android, telephony, conference

I would like to get any suggestions on detecting conference call for on going call. I looked at the documentation but didn't got any hint from it. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: refer to this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893757/how-to-identify-when-entering-a-conference-call)

Comment: Thanks Olu I saw that but im really looking for any workaround  :)